# Strict-Transport-Security not working or testing wrong?

Tags: apache, security, webserver, jetty, embedded-jetty

I read an article about the HTTP header at `https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/what-is-hsts-and-how-do-i-use-it/` and I am trying to see if our production Jetty server can use it. Before modifying the production code, I wrote a simple Java code that has Jetty running and added the header, the curl script also dumps the header but in my browser, I can always access my web page via HTTP.
Here is the sample code I wrote

```
public class BlockingServlet extends HttpServlet{

    protected void doGet(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader("X-Xss-Protection", "1; mode=block");
        response.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload");
        response.getWriter().println("{ \"status\": \"ok\"}");
    }
}
```

Now here is my curl call and the output:

```
curl http://localhost:8090/status -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 Apr 2018 01:28:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Content-Length: 18
Server: Jetty(9.4.3.v20170317)
```

Also, when I type `http://localhost:8090/status` in my browser, I can see the JSON output which after populating the header must not work as my server is not running https at all because if I explicitly type `https` I cannot access the url.

What is wrong in my understanding?